# Complex navigation system (and NavBar) between view controllers with the same information

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I need help regarding a problem that I have been wanting to solve for a long time.
It is a navigation between view controllers (children) that take information from the parent. The parent is updated if there is a notification. And I want the children to update instantly along with the parent.
It would be a Home controller where I show basic information.
Then a button inside the Home controller that would take the View Controller that has the navigation that I mentioned.

I attach a basic scheme so you can understand it better

[image: scheme]

I would like to receive an idea even if it is basic in a programmatic way to start thinking about logic.
It would also help me a lot how to make the `TOP NAVIGATION BAR` between steps (step 1, step 2...), and when I click on any step that opens the child corresponding to that step.

The `User` type is nothing more than a dictionary with Strings, Ints and some data. (I can did the notification system and works, i only mention that can work in this way)

I have also thought that when I press the home controller button it will load 4 view controllers (one for each step) and it will consume load time, right?

Any help would get me out of stress
Thanks a lot!!

```
// Home controller
    class HomeController: UIViewController {
        
        let showSteps: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSteps), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addSubview(showSteps)
        }
        
        @objc func showSteps() {
            
            let controller = ShowSteps()
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        
    }


    // UIViewController with Navigation Bar
    class ShowSteps: UIViewController {

        private var user: User?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            // update the User variable
            Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: "XXX") { user in
                self.user = user
            }
            // listen notifications to update the user
            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUser), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateUser"), object: nil)
        
            /// 1. HERE I NEED TO ADD A NAVIGATION BAR IN THE TOP OF THE VIEW, THAT APPEAR IN ALL CHILDS
            /// 2. I NEED TO NAVIGATE TO OTHER STEPS WITH A FUNCTION
            
        
        }
        
        @objc func dissmissView(){
            /// 3. how can i remove from view all childs 4 in this case. but can be 6 o 7.... And then dismiss actual ShowSteps
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        @objc func updateUser() {
            // update user if notification called
            Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: "XXX") { user in
                self.user = user
            }
        }

    }


    // that is a child example
    class VCexample1: UIViewController {
        
        /// 4. how can i see the navigation bar that has the parent? How can i send to other step from here?
        /// 5. how can i get the user variable from ShowSteps?
        /// 6. how can i navigate to other step from here?
        ///
        let BarButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToOtherStep), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            /// show user data
        }
        

    }


    // that is a other child example
    class VCexample2: UIViewController {
        
        ...

    }
    // that is a other child example
    class VCexample3: UIViewController {
        
        ...

    }
    // that is a other child example
    class VCexample4: UIViewController {
        
        ...

    }
```

IS BASIC BASIC CODE. ITS NOT PERFECT. I HAVE PUT IT WITH ERRORS BUT SHORT SO THAT IT IS BETTER UNDERSTOOD

Comment: Please ask just one question.

Comment: You need to use Notification Center to get user data updates. A view controller when appearing can register to some specific notification so it can update its contents.

Comment: I just put some code what i need help with. thanks for all help @matt

Comment: A navigation bar can not be shared. Did you try to see how you could manage this in storyboard ? This could help you design your views and see how you can add control to navigate from 1 view to another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PtitXav! The problem is that I don't want to use storyboards. I'm doing it only with code. It is not possible to create a class that is TabBar for example and that is seen by the parent and all the children. and that when I press a button on the tabbar, I execute a function in the parent that takes me to the chosen child? I don't know how to do that with code. The most important thing for me is to be able to collect the user information in the children, from the parent. Then i will think to show custom bar, there are some questions that I will solve little by little

Comment: A child can execute a function in a parent using delegation : the parent is access via a delegate variable in the child that is set at child creation. When an action is made in the child this can call the specific method in its delegate (which is the parent ) . If the button is in your bar , then it can call the parent with delegate callback. The parent could then tell tabbar what child to show.

Comment: @nacho1111 If you're parent with stepper view that has access to all of you're child vc, there is good approach to use protocol on you're parent that has conform by you're childs.

Comment: If i make a delegate in parent, only can call functions or variables too?. I think delegate is best option too. i have a question. If firebase fire new data, and ShowSteps Controller update User, automatically update user in childrens?. Obviously the children get user from the parent, but I don't know if it would update by itself or if I have to do something else. Thanks!!  Some code for delegate helps me a lot. Thanks again @PtitXav and reza kHonsari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example of delegation :

```
// User data
struct UserData {
    var name: String
}

// this how child get info from parentVC
protocol childVCDelegate {
    // delegete user func or var (only one may be usefull)
    func getUserData() -> UserData
    func getUserName() -> String
    var userData: UserData {get set}
}

// the parent view controller who keep the user data
class ParentVC: UIViewController, childVCDelegate {
    var userData: UserData = UserData(name: "nacho111")
    
    func getUserData() -> UserData {
        userData
    }

    func getUserName() -> String {
        userData.name
    }
}

// child VC with a label updated with user name from parentVC
class ChildVC: UIViewController {
    var label = UILabel()
    var delegate: childVCDelegate?
    
    // either a copy of user in child view
    var userInChildVC: UserData?
    
    // either access user in Parent VC
    var userInParentVC: UserData? {
        delegate?.userData
    }
    
    // fonction to register in notification center to get userData changes from parentVC
    func userDataChanged() {
        // only one of the 2 options is usefull
        userInChildVC = delegate?.getUserData()
        label.text = userInChildVC?.name
        
        label.text = delegate?.userData.name
        
        label.text = delegate?.getUserName()
    }
}

// the tab bar which create a childVC and connect it to the parent
// via delegate property of ChildVC
class TabBar: UIViewController {

    var childVC: [ChildVC] = []

    // visible child VC
    var visibleChildVC: Int? {
        willSet {
            if let index = visibleChildVC {
                childVC[index].view.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        didSet {
            if let index = visibleChildVC {
                childVC[index].view.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createChildVC(withParentVC parentVC: ParentVC,
                       visible: Bool = false) {
        let ch1 = ChildVC()
        ch1.delegate = parentVC
        childVC.append(ch1)
        // adding child VC view in view hierarchy : optional
        view.addSubview(ch1.view)
        if visible {
            visibleChildVC = childVC.count - 1
        } else {
            ch1.view.isHidden = true
        }
    }


    func displayChildVC(atIndex index: Int) {
        visibleChildVC = index
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! its simple and works. I only need to jump from child to other child. Do you know how can i do that? thanks @PtitXav

Comment: Added a simple way to select one child VC. BTW this could also be done view page scrolled view. You could also add animation for view transition.